# Fast Text unsupervised model loss with Python API

Tags: python, fasttext

Is there any way to get the model loss for the unsupervised training of models using Fast Text with the python API? At the moment I am doing the training using the C++ model and loading it using the Python API.

For e.g., I first run the following code to tweak hyper parameters

```
./fasttext skipgram \
-input /data/cleaned.txt \
-output /models/cleaned-model \
-epoch 12000 \
-minCount 2 \
-ws 3
```

The command-line interface gives an estimate of the loss like so:

```
Progress: 100.0% words/sec/thread:  103006 lr:  0.000000 loss:  1.803622 ETA:   0h 0m
```

However, doing the same using the Python API:

```
import fastText
model = fastText.train_unsupervised('/data/cleaned.txt', 
                                    epoch=12000, 
                                    minCount=2, 
                                    ws=3)
```

This trains but does not output the loss? I checked increasing the verbosity level `verbosity=3` in the training function options but nothing happens. Is this a missing feature or something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the python script from the shell, it prints the desired output.

Maybe you're using Jupyter Notebook. In this case, currently there's not a simple way to see the output in the notebook.